# NativeExpressAdView not working

Tags: android, admob

When I add ads, they do not appear in xml ,

Here is screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/loROw.png

when the application is running I exit the application

please help me

Answer (score 0):

Ads will show only after you install it on real device.
You have to add your test device while loading Ad like this.

```
adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder()
              .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
              .addTestDevice("your test device ID")
              .build());
```